# Do I delete instance data of a com object in release or in destructor?

Tags: c++, com

Release is supposed to, as the name says, release instance data. This is also the task of a destructor in c++.
Now where should i release instance data? Which one is called first?

Comment: Show sample code, otherwise it is extremely unclear what you are talking about.

Comment: Last `Release` calls destructor. As simple as this. `Release` is reponsible for counting, and resource freeing is in destructor.

Answer (score 3):

A COM object keeps track of how many times `AddRef` and `Release` have been called on it.
This is called the **RefCount**.

When the RefCount drops to zero, it means no one is holding a reference to the object anymore, and ***it deletes itself***.

You and your code never really know exactly what other elements of a program may be holding a reference to a COM object, so you should not explicitly delete the object.

Rather, you should call `Release` when you are done with it.  When the last `Release` is called, the object will delete its own data.

Answer (score 3):

`Release` is supposed to decrement the reference count. Only if the reference count reaches zero, the object is destroyed an the destructor called.

Comment: **the object is destroyed and the destructor is called.*